# how to add a class to post_class();

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How can I add the bootstrap class md-col-9 to this element when the classes are being pulled through by php?

```
<li <?php post_class(); ?>>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **optional parameter**, which can be added to the post_class().

If you need to add only 1 class, then you can make like this `<?php post_class( 'class-name' ); ?>`

If you need to add more then 1 class, then your code may look like this

```
<?php

$classes = array(
    'class1',
    'class2',
    'class3',
);
?>

<div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

You can read more about it at official documentation here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it's actually very simple. I added my class like this:

```
<li <?php post_class('col-md-9'); ?>>
</li>
```